# Not able to access protected variables

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have created a simple test project to use a class as a custom List type and have a couple of questions regarding the use of different syntax when declaring variables.

I have a class called `CustomerInfo` which defines all the variables required to be stored for the customer information which will be added to a list as seen below:

```
    protected string Firstname { get; set; }

    protected string Surname { get; set; }

    protected int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return Age;
        }
        set
        {
            if(value < 0)
            {
                throw new AgeException("Age cannot be a value below 0");
            }
            else
            {
                Age = value;
            }
        }
    }

    protected string Gender { get; set; }
```

Questions:
1) Why does the code below not allow me to access the protected variables in the `CustomerInfo` class even though I am inheriting the class?

```
class Program : CustomerInfo
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomerInfo custInfo = new CustomerInfo();
        custInfo.Firstname = "Richard"; //not working
        custInfo.Surname = "Smith"; //not working

        List<CustomerInfo> custList = new List<CustomerInfo>();
        custList.Add(custInfo);
    }
}
```

2) When looking at Windows Forms applications they already contain an inheritence of Form in the code of any Form you create. If you have to inherit a class to access the protected variables & methods it has, how can you access the variables if each form already has an inheritance that you cannot remove?

Thanks

Comment: try rebuilding your solution

Comment: the answer to number 2 is that you can inherit the form in a class then inherit from that class

Comment: It looks like you have 2 (mostly) unrelated questions.  Consider asking these questions one at a time - you will likely get better answers.

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen Rebuilding hasn't worked & thanks for the second answer.

Comment: 1) Search and read up on c# access modifiers. You can only access protected members in a derived class. 2) The form derives `Form` so that's why you can access it. Remove the `: Form` and you will get compiler errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of inheritance.  Inheritance is designed to represent a relationship between two objects where one is a more specialized version of the other.  This is sometimes called an "is-a" relationship.

Consider the following class definitions:

```
class Fruit {}
class Apple : Fruit {}
class Banana: Fruit {}
```

In this case, `Apple` and `Banana` both inherit from `Fruit` to express the "is-a" relationship - a `Banana` *is a* `Fruit`.  In object-oriented design, this allows you to write a method like this:

```
class Person
{
    public void Eat(Fruit fruit) {}
    {
        // stuff goes here
    }
}
```

The `Eat` method allows the `Person` class to eat anything that is a `Fruit`, including classes that derive from `Fruit`.  So you can do the following:

```
Person person = new Person();
Apple apple = new Apple();
Banana banana = new Banana();

person.Eat(apple);
person.Eat(banana);
```

---

Compare this to the class definition you have written:

```
class Program : CustomerInfo
```

In the language of OOP, this says "a `Program` *is a* `CustomerInfo`."  I don't think that's what you want.  Using the `protected` keyword doesn't make sense here because your inheritance relationship doesn't make sense.  If `Program` is supposed to be able to access `CustomerInfo` members, they should be declared `public` or `internal`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the detailed examples. This makes inheritance much clearer now. What would the benefits (or drawbacks) be of using internal over public for my example?

Comment: @Tatrick `internal` members are visible to all classes *in the same assembly*, whereas `public` members are visible to all classes regardless of their assembly.  If your project only has one assembly (i.e. DLL or EXE), they will behave basically the same, but if you develop a library that is used by others you may want to "hide" implementation by making classes or members internal.

Answer (score 2):

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member
>   is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.
>   Source [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected)

```
CustomerInfo custInfo = new CustomerInfo();
custInfo.Firstname = "Richard"; //not working
custInfo.Surname = "Smith"; //not working
```

This code is not working because your custInfo's `Firtsname` and `Surname` are not accessible in the `Program` class. But you should be able to do the following, as your `Program` class is inherited from `CustomerInfo` :

```
Firstname = "Richard";
Surname = "Smith";
```

For the second question you can do something like the following:

```
Class1 : Form
{
     // here will be your protected members
}
Class2 : Class1
```

Comment: Hi Samvel, thanks for the response. Firstname = "Richard" etc is not working. Your answer to the second question is what I needed. Any ideas as to why the first suggestion isn't working?

Comment: @Tatrick what do you mean saying `Firstname = "Richard"` is not working? It's giving compilation error?

Comment: @Tatrick you cannot create a new instance of `CustomerInfo` and try to access it's protected member's if you are in the body of Program. There are accessible only the Firstname and Surname of that Program class and not the once that have new instance in the Program

Comment: I just looked at what error it was giving and it was because it's under a static method. Moving it to a public one has solved the issue. How do I make the custInfo's 'Firstname' and 'Surname' accessible from the program class but keeping them protected so they cannot be modified externally while the program is running?

Comment: @Tatrick you can make them `protected internal` but anyway even if they were `private` they can be modified via `Reflection`

Comment: Okay, bit of a side tracking now but is there any way to counter this from occurring?